# С чем может быть связано нестабильное поведение QListWidget?(Python3, PyQt5)

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qlistwidget, qscrollarea

**Я только что задавал вопрос касательно кода ниже. Но теперь у меня появилась еще одна проблема.**

У меня есть три класса - `ListWidget`, `Label` и `MyWindow`. `ListWidget` создает резиновую ленту, а `Label` создает виджет QLabel с закругленным изображением. **На эти классы не стоит обращать внимания, они точно правильно выполняют свои функции. Проблема(проблемы) в классе `MyWindow`.**

1. Тут я создаю кнопку `simple_btn`, которая потом попадает в
   вертикальный контейнер `box2`. Пока она не выполняет и не должна
   выполнять никаких функций.
2. Создаю `listWidget` - копию класса `ListWidget`, который наполняю виджетами QLable(`label1`, `label2`, `label3`), полученными из класса `Label`.
3. Создаю `scrollArea`(QScrollArea), но пока нигде не размещаю.
4. Создаю QGridLayout - `box1`, куда первым виджетом(0, 0) добавляю
   `listWidget`.
5. К виджетам `label1` , `label2` и `label3` привязываю метод класса `MyWindow` - `click()`(при этом передаю этому методу аргумент `num`),
   который с помощью `hide()` скрывает `listWidget` и создает
   привязанный к `scrollArea` контейнер QGridLayout - `box3`, если он
   еще не был создан. `box3` наполняется кнопками, число которых зависит от аргумента `num`. В вертикальный
   контейнер `box2` попадает кнопка `back_btn`.
6. К кнопке `back_btn` привязваю метод `onButton`. Этот метод должен
   удалять все виджеты контейнера `box3`, скрывать `scrollArea` с
   помощью `hide()` и делать обратно видимым `listWidget` с помощью
   `show()`.

**`В чем проблема:`**

Если выполнить некоторую комбинацию действий несколько раз(нажать на какой-нибудь из виджетов QLabel, а потом вернуться обратно кнопкой `back_btn`), часто `listWidget` перестает нормально работать. **Виджеты внутри него перестают менять свое пололожение в зависимости от размера окна.** Это происходит достаточно спонтанно(чаще всего при нажатии на `label3`) и я не могу объяснить, что именно вызывает проблему. На другом компьютере происходит то же самое.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вот правильное отображение виджетов:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Баг происходит при любом положении виджетов:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Честно говоря, я очень огорчен этим, и мне очень нужна помощь. Не могу представить, как это можно загуглить, куда копать. Пожалуйста, подскажите, что может приводить к этой ошибке?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class ListWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.setWindowTitle('ListWidget')
        #self.setStyleSheet('border-style: hidden;')
        self.resize(520, 400)

        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.setEditTriggers(self.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAction)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.ContiguousSelection)

        self.setFlow(self.LeftToRight)
        self.setWrapping(True)
        self.setResizeMode(self.Adjust)

        self.setSpacing(10)

        self._rubberPos  = None
        self._rubberBand = None #QtWidgets.QRubberBand(QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)

    def makeItem(self, lb):
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self)
        item.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(140, 140))
        self.setItemWidget(item, lb)


class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setMaximumSize(140, 140)
        self.setMinimumSize(140, 140)
        self.radius = 10 

        self.target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())  
        self.target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)    

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(140, 140, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.simple_btn  = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        self.simple_btn.setFixedSize(100, 60)

        self.listWidget = ListWidget()

        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.content_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.content_widget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.label1 = Label('picture1.png')
        self.listWidget.makeItem(self.label1)
        self.label1.clicked.connect(lambda num=2: self.click(num))
        self.label2 = Label('picture1.png')
        self.listWidget.makeItem(self.label2)
        self.label2.clicked.connect(lambda num=3: self.click(num))
        self.label3 = Label('picture1.png')
        self.listWidget.makeItem(self.label3)
        self.label3.clicked.connect(lambda num=4: self.click(num))

        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.box2.addWidget(self.simple_btn, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)                                     
        self.box1.addWidget(self.listWidget, 0, 0)
        self.box1.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.box1.addLayout(self.box2, 0, 1) 

    def click(self, num):
        self.listWidget.hide()

        if not hasattr(self, 'box3'):
            self.box1.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 0, 0)
            self.box3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.content_widget)
        else:
            self.scrollArea.show()

        for n in range(1, num):
            btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'Button{n}')
            self.box3.addWidget(btn, n-1, 0)

        self.back_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Back', clicked=self.onButton) 
        self.back_btn.setFixedSize(100, 60)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.back_btn, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

    def onButton(self):
        self.back_btn.deleteLater()
        col = 0
        for row in range(self.box3.rowCount()):
            if self.box3.itemAtPosition(row, col) is not None:
                w = self.box3.itemAtPosition(row, col).widget()
            w.deleteLater()
        self.scrollArea.hide()
        self.listWidget.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я переписал только `class MyWindow` и отметил основные изменения.

Пробуйте.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class ListWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.setWindowTitle('ListWidget')
        #self.setStyleSheet('border-style: hidden;')
        self.resize(520, 400)

        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.setEditTriggers(self.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAction)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.ContiguousSelection)

        self.setFlow(self.LeftToRight)
        self.setWrapping(True)
        self.setResizeMode(self.Adjust)

        self.setSpacing(10)

        self._rubberPos  = None
        self._rubberBand = None #QtWidgets.QRubberBand(QtWidgets.QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)

    def makeItem(self, lb):
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self)
        item.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(140, 140))
        self.setItemWidget(item, lb)


class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setMaximumSize(140, 140)
        self.setMinimumSize(140, 140)
        self.radius = 10 

        self.target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())  
        self.target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)    

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(140, 140, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(310, 190)                                         # +

        self.simple_btn  = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        self.simple_btn.setFixedSize(100, 60)

        listWidget = ListWidget()                                             # +

        self._listLabel = []                                                  # +!!!
        self.label1 = Label('head3.png')
        self.label1.clicked.connect(lambda num=2: self.click(num))
        self._listLabel.append(self.label1)
        self.label2 = Label('Ok.png')
        self.label2.clicked.connect(lambda num=3: self.click(num))
        self._listLabel.append(self.label2)
        self.label3 = Label('im.png')
        self.label3.clicked.connect(lambda num=4: self.click(num))
        self._listLabel.append(self.label3)

        for lb in self._listLabel:
            listWidget.makeItem(lb)        

        self.back_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Back', clicked=self.onButton)   # +!!!
        self.back_btn.setFixedSize(100, 60)   

        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.box2.addWidget(self.simple_btn, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.back_btn, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)     # +++  
        self.back_btn.hide()                                                   # +++    

        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)                                     
        self.box1.addWidget(listWidget, 0, 0)
        self.box1.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.box1.addLayout(self.box2, 0, 1) 

    def click(self, num):
        scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        content_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        scrollArea.setWidget(content_widget)
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        box3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(content_widget)
        self.box1.addWidget(scrollArea, 0, 0)
        for n in range(1, num):
            btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'Button{n}')
            box3.addWidget(btn, n-1, 0)
        self.back_btn.show()

    def onButton(self):
        self.back_btn.hide()

        listWidget = ListWidget()
        for lb in self._listLabel:
            listWidget.makeItem(lb) 
        self.box1.addWidget(listWidget, 0, 0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я очень вам благодарен. Сегодня весь день пытался что-то придумать, отследить логику, но безуспешно. Сейчас буду все разбирать. Спасибо вам большое

Comment: Прошу прощения, что мучаю вас. Возник небольшой вопрос - меня интересует судьба элементов `scrollArea`, `listWidget`, `box3` и кнопок `btn` после нажатия на `back_btn` и виджеты QLаbel. Я правильно понимаю, что по верх них создаются новые элементы, а прежние оседают в оперативной памяти, пока окно не будет закрыто? Если так, то должно быть это может увеличить ресурсозатратность приложения? Я собираюсь после создания нового элемента удалять старый. Как вы думаете, моя идея плохая?

Comment: Сейчас подумал, может быть, они сами удаляются?

Comment: @MAXIM045  я не проверял, попробуйте запустить диспетчер задач и понаблюдать что происходит.

Comment: Я создал две кнопки. Сначала добавил первую на место (0, 0) в QGridLayout, а потом на это же место вторую. С помощью `hasattr` попробовал проверить существование первой кнопки. Класс ее находит, т.е., видимо, элементы не удаляются

Comment: В диспетчере задач затрата памяти увеличивается. Как думаете, будет ли правильно удалять элементы?

Comment: Сейчас подумал, что, наверное, ерунду говорю. Название элементов не изменяется же, значит, они должны перезаписываться. Удаление не поможет. Но, я не понимаю, с чем связан рост застрат памяти:)

Comment: @MAXIM045  почитайте может что-то интересное там есть https://habr.com/ru/post/417215/

Comment: Спасибо большое :)